# What logical operator is equivalent to "is like"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Currently I'm learning some logic and while surfing the net I found this post that states:

> ["A samurai without a sword is like a samurai with the sword but without the sword"](http://9gag.com/gag/aDjqAoG)

So I was wondering if I could prove that the statement is a **Tautology**. But first I wasn't sure how to interpret the "is like". What I ended up doing is treating it as *biconditional*. So let `P = Samurai with a sword` then, the expression would be $\neg{P} \iff (P \wedge \neg{P})$. Using a truth table I was able to confirm this to be a tautology:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
P & \neg{P} & P \wedge \neg{P} & \neg{P} \implies (P \wedge \neg{P}) & (P \wedge \neg{P}) \implies \neg{P} \\ \hline
\text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F} & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Is my reasoning correct? Should I treate the "is like" as *biconditional*

**Update:** I just realized that I was wrong and the statement is not a **tautology**. The table should be:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
P & \neg{P} & P \wedge \neg{P} & \neg{P} \implies (P \wedge \neg{P}) & (P \wedge \neg{P}) \implies \neg{P} \\ \hline
\text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F} & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

But I'm still not sure if my interpretation of the statement is correct.

Comment: Whether or not treating $\iff$ as the biconditional is another matter, but your truth table is wrong: the bottom value in the fourth column should be $F$.

Comment: $\neg P \Leftrightarrow (P \wedge \neg P)$ is not a tautology.

Comment: Yep you are right I edited the question

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to analyze 'is like' as a truth-functional operator at all. Also note that your $P$ isn't even a statement!

Comment: You are right!!! A statement would be something like: `P =The samurai has a sword`. With that said it seems like the phrase can't be analyzed without rephrasing the whole thing, which would end up removing "is like"!

Comment: I suppose, in some cases, it might be a good idea to interpret "is like" like equivalence ("having no milk" is like "not having milk"), it does not feel entirely right though. It feels closer to isomorphic in a sense =). Here, however, I feel the second part of the sentence is the problem. It would probably be interpreted as: 'a samurai without a sword' $\Leftrightarrow$ 'a samurai with a sword' $\wedge$ 'a samurai without a sword'. and I feel the right hand case will be false here. I think you need to treat it as an atomic or break it down even further in some way. Probably rephrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S(x): \text{x is a samurai}$, P(x): $\text{x has a sword}$.

My suggestion is:

$$\forall x, S(x) \implies (\neg P(x) \iff P(x) \land \neg P(x))$$

This is a tautology iff there are no samurais or if every samurai has got a sword (which even makes some sense).

Comment: I like your suggestion. How would it look like if there were no samurai?

Comment: I think i got it how it would look like if there were no samurai: $\forall{x},S(x) = \text{False}$ and $\neg{P(x)} \iff P(x) \wedge \neg{P(x)} = \text{False}$ then $\text{False} \implies \text{False}$ which would make it true.

Comment: Actually $\neg P(x) \iff P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ could still be true, while assuming the inexistence of samurai (this would mean everybody, samurai or not, had swords), because $False \implies True $ is still true.

Comment: Being a tautology is an even stronger property than being valid for a predicate-calculus sentence.  $\forall x ~.~ S(x) \Rightarrow (\neg P(x) \Leftrightarrow (P(x) \wedge \neg P(x)))$ is not even valid.  I concur with those who call for rephrasing the statement.

Comment: I don't know if it's clear, but the quantifier refers to the whole implication. As for the tautology property, I can see your point, it's not totally correct to call this a tautology.

Comment: @JoãoC.  Yes, it's clear that the scope of the implication is everything that follows it.  As you point out, in a world in which someone is a samurai and someone lacks a sword the sentence is false.  Hence, it is not valid.  That's all I wanted to point out.  How the sentence in the OP should be translated is a different matter, which hinges on how it is to be understood.

Comment: Yes, I agree. IMO, asserting the sentence as true  is saying that "every samurai has a sword", so samurai without sword do not exist and the statement is vacuosly true.